# Deploy Angular to shared drive

Tags: angular, typescript

in angular.json I have:

> "outputPath": "Y:\Sites\MySite",

I run ng builg but I get:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'D:\ClientApp\Y:\MySite\browser'
See "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-T07572\angular-errors.log" for further 
details.
```

Why is it trying to write to "D:\ClientApp\Y:\MySite\browser" ?

Comment: Have you checked the log file? `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-T07572\angular-errors.log`

Comment: yes, the thing is, why is it trying to write to "D:\ClientApp\Y:\MySite\browser" ? its trying to write it in the same app's folder

Answer (score 0):

Angular's `outputPath` is relative to the project's working directory. You might want to create an `npm build` command which does `ng build` and then [copy](https://home.csulb.edu/%7Emurdock/xcopy.html) the output directory to your other drive.

Comment: I was able to do this with previous versions of angular, something changed? (this is version 17)